# "All in a day's work"

Tags: idiom-meaning

What does "All in a day's work" mean? The online dictionaries aren't very detailed on that. How did this idiom come to be? Was there some meaningful context to it originally?

Comment: General Reference. [If something difficult, unpleasant, or strange is all in a day's work for someone, it is a usual part of their job](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/all-in-a-day-s-work) *- When you're a nurse, cleaning up vomit is all in a day's work.*

Comment: It's very much like saying you do something before breakfast, but more professional and less impressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All in a day's work" refers to any task that is done routinely.  It can be negative (e.g. tasks you don't care for doing), neutral, ironic, etc. based upon speaker preferences.

As for origins, the definitions made reference to nautical navigation, and I believe they were referring to [Celestial Navigation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_navigation)  Celestial Navigation involved using a celestial body (e.g. the sun, moon, stars) to navigate oceans.  They could correct their course by using a sextant and the visible horizon in relation to various celestial bodies.  It had to be done frequently (though I'm not sure how often), thus is was part of a day's work.

Definitions:

-part of what is expected; typical or normal. *I don't particularly like to cook, but it's all in a day's work. Cleaning up after other people is all in a day's work for a busboy.*

-Expected and normal. This phrase is sometimes used as an ironic comment on an unpleasant but not abnormal situation. The expression possibly alludes to the nautical term day's work , defined in 1789 as the reckoning of a ship's course during the 24 hours from noon to noon. [c. 1800]
[Dictionary.com][2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/all+in+a+day%27s+work)

Hope this has been helpful, and answered your question.

Comment: Celestial navigation is better done at night, though :)

Comment: That may be true.  It is most accurate when five points of reference are used, but I imagine you would want to do during daytime as well to ensure you do not go excessively off course.  Also, the moon, planets and stars can be viewed in daylight.